# Delete confirmation with Sweet alert in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a comment delete button in vue components.

```
<button class="button" style="background-color: grey;" @click="destroy">Delete</button>
```

When the button clicked will call the method "destroy"

```
destroy(){
            swal({
                    title: "Delete this comment?",
                    text: "Are you sure? You won't be able to revert this!",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete it!",
                    closeOnConfirm: true
                },
                function(){
                    axios.delete('/comment/' + this.comment.id + '/delete');

                    $(this.$el).fadeOut(300, () => {
                        return toastr.success('Comment deleted.');
                    });
                });
        },
```

i expect when alert come out, if users clicked confirm button then process to delete, but seem like when user clicked the delete function are not executed. What is the problems here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` context inside SWAL's callback function is the SWAL instance and not the Vue instance! This means that `this.comment.id` and `this.$el` are probably `undefined` and, thus, the function don't execute and would result in a [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError).

To resolve this,

- Use [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

  ```
  swal({
    title: "Delete this comment?",
    text: "Are you sure? You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete it!",
    closeOnConfirm: true
  }, () => {
    axios.delete('/comment/' + this.comment.id + '/delete');
    $(this.$el).fadeOut(300, () => toastr.success('Comment deleted.'));
  })
  ```
- Capture `this`

  ```
  let inst = this;
  swal({
    title: "Delete this comment?",
    text: "Are you sure? You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete it!",
    closeOnConfirm: true
  }, function onDelete(){
    axios.delete('/comment/' + inst.comment.id + '/delete');
    $(inst.$el).fadeOut(300, () => toastr.success('Comment deleted.'));
  })
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is not only a this context error.
SweetAlert is promise-based, so you need to call your axios request, in a Promise.prototype.then() method.

```js
swal({
  title: "Delete this comment?",
  text: "Are you sure? You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete it!",
  closeOnConfirm: true
})
.then( () => {
  axios.delete('/comment/' + this.comment.id + '/delete');
  $(this.$el).fadeOut(300, () => toastr.success('Comment deleted.'));
})
```